Create a createTrustline on Steller
i am trying to create a createTrustline on Stellar blockchain, but i keep getting error on this line of code
trustlineOp := txnbuild.ChangeTrust{
        Line: txnbuild.ChangeTrustAsset{
            Code:   "USDC",
            Issuer: issuerUSDC,
        },
        Limit: "10000",
    }

keep saying invalid composite literal type txnbuild.ChangeTrustAsset but i dont know what is wrong...

full code here
func createTrustline(wallet *Wallet) {
    kp, err := keypair.ParseFull(wallet.SecretKey)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error parsing wallet keypair:", err)
    }

    accountRequest := horizonclient.AccountRequest{AccountID: kp.Address()}
    account, err := client.AccountDetail(accountRequest)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error fetching wallet account details:", err)
    }

    // Define the trustline operation
    trustlineOp := txnbuild.ChangeTrust{
        Line: txnbuild.ChangeTrustAsset{
            Code:   "USDC",
            Issuer: issuerUSDC,
        },
        Limit: "10000",
    }

    timeBounds := txnbuild.NewTimeout(int64(30 * time.Second.Milliseconds())) // 30 seconds from now
    preconditions := txnbuild.Preconditions{
        TimeBounds: timeBounds,
    }

    // Create the transaction with the trustline operation
    tx, err := txnbuild.NewTransaction(
        txnbuild.TransactionParams{
            SourceAccount:        &account,
            IncrementSequenceNum: true,
            Operations:           []txnbuild.Operation{&trustlineOp},
            BaseFee:              txnbuild.MinBaseFee,
            Preconditions:        preconditions,
        },
    )
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error creating trustline transaction:", err)
    }

    // Sign the transaction
    tx, err = tx.Sign(network.PublicNetworkPassphrase, kp)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error signing trustline transaction:", err)
    }

    // Submit the transaction
    resp, err := client.SubmitTransaction(tx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error submitting trustline transaction:", err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("Trustline created successfully. Transaction hash: %s\n", resp.Hash)
}

